# How do I plot multiple lines within the same graph and each represents targeted group by using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line-plot

If I would like to plot 3 lines within the same graph, each represents the numbers of count from the relative sentiment (POSITIVE, NEUTRAL, NEGATIVE). The graph does not show what I expect. By using "label", does it mean I select only one group (for example, 'POSITIVE') from "new sentiment" column to plot the line graph? How do I expand the x-axis more broader?

```
date    new_sentiment   count
0   2020-03-06  POSITIVE    1
1   2020-03-17  NEGATIVE    1
2   2020-03-17  NEUTRAL     1
3   2020-03-18  NEUTRAL     1
4   2020-03-23  NEUTRAL     1
... ... ... ...
757 2021-05-30  NEGATIVE    89
758 2021-05-30  POSITIVE    13
759 2021-05-31  NEGATIVE    13
760 2021-05-31  NEUTRAL     11
761 2021-05-31  POSITIVE    2
```

```
plt.plot(data['date'],data['count'], label = "POSITIVE", color='black')
plt.plot(data['date'],data['count'], label = "NEGATIVE", color='red')
plt.plot(data['date'],data['count'], label = "NEUTRAL", color='green')
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),rotation=45)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=20))
plt.xlim('2021-01-01','2021-06-10')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: _By using "label", does it mean..._ -> No. Use `import seaborn as sns` and then `sns.lineplot(data=data, x='date', y='count', hue='new_sentiment')`.

Comment: How do I expand the interval of x-axis a bit wider? I am looking for the syntax to execute the plot.

Comment: `seaborn` is just a high-level api for `matplotlib` so the same methods used for changing the matplotlib axis work for the seaborn axis level plots like `sns.lineplot`.

Comment: You can also do `ax = data.pivot(index='date', columns='new_sentiment', values='count').plot()`.